# How do I use ruby to read the source a uri that im hosting on my own computer?

Tags: ruby, wikipedia, open-uri

I trying to get ruby to read the source of a url thats being hosted on my own computer. I've tried using open-uri gem with:

```
source = open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/wikipedia_en_all_nopic_01_2012/A/Mick%20Jagger.html', &:read)
```

With normal external urls this works fine but it raises multiple errors when i try to access the url im hosting on my computer. Does anyone have any idea how to this? Heres the command line error report:

```
/Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish': incorrect header check (Zlib::DataError)
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:262:in `ensure in inflater'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:262:in `inflater'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:274:in `read_body_0'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:328:in `block (2 levels) in open_http'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1415:in `block (2 levels) in transport_request'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:162:in `reading_body'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `catch'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `transport_request'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1378:in `request'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:319:in `block in open_http'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:313:in `open_http'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:723:in `buffer_open'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:703:in `open'
from /Users/rorycampbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
from testurl.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE: I'm using kiwix server to host the URL

Comment: Does it work if you use `curl` in the shell?

Comment: That's just the stack trace at the point of the error, please post the error message you get.

Comment: I added the error in. Using curl in the shell works fine.

Comment: The open-uri gem uses the file:// protocol for local files not http://. You could try running http://pow.cx/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `net/http` instead.

```
require 'net/http'
source = Net::HTTP.get URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/wikipedia_en_all_nopic_01_2012/A/Mick%20Jagger.html')
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried the open and that did nothing for me, so I tried the net http and was able to request my local. I used localhost and not the IP though, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm new to ruby so not sure but from what I've read, I believe there was a bug in the understanding of the coding. HTTparty gem worked fine though.

Comment: Hmm. Just tried it on ruby 2.1 (i was using 1.9.3 before. No issue either.

Comment: I guess it was something to do with the fact that I using Kiwix to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want you use a URL if it's on the local machine?  Why not just give the path?

That error sounds like there's something wrong with the actual file you're trying to parse, or the way it's being served by the way.  From reading about Kiwix server it sounds like the latter...On the Kiwix site it says that it uses some type compression method called openzim which is most likely why open-uri can't find a way to parse it.

You could try nokogiri and see if it has a problem parsing it. But since it seems like you're trying to open/manipulate a zim file in ruby, I'd look for a zim library for ruby instead of trying to serve it.

Here: 
https://github.com/chrisistuff/zim-ruby

I've never dealt with kiwix/zim, so I don't know if this one works but it was the only one the a google search for 'zim ruby' came back with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with kiwix. I extracted all the URLs in a file called hrefs.txt (in my case it was the german project gutenberg) and used `wget` to download each of them:

```
f = File.open("hrefs.txt", "r")
f.each_line do |url|
  #filename = url.split("/").last.gsub!(/[^A-Za-z]/, '')[0..-4]
  system "wget #{url}"
end
f.close
```